# как добавить метод в класс не вписывая его в определение класса?

Tags: c++

В файле–описании имеется класс `Alfa` и в него нужно добавить метод, но сделать это нужно не в том же файле (не в определении класса), а в файле, к которому он подключен. Возможно ли это?

Comment: Невозможно, но можно сделать обёртку, в которую добавить необходимый метод и через неё использовать.

Comment: В голову приходят только костыльные способы, которые даже не хочется рекомендовать.

Comment: Может посмотреть в сторону паттерна декоратор. или адаптер например?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**режим стандарта** методов в с++ нет, поэтому ответ только такой - переписать стандарт.**режим стандарта выключен**

В целом, все возможно. Нужно просто  определить функцию, у которой первый параметр - указатель или ссылка (константная) на объект типа Alfa. А потом подкупить комитет, чтобы они все тики проголосовали за [p0079r0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0079r0.pdf). И после этого заработает вот такой код

```
struct B;
// 'this' makes 'bar' an extension method
void bar(B* this, int x);
B b;
b.bar(1); // invokes bar(&b, 1)
```